# How to access app engine datastore by android app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created app engine app (using Python)([devappdemo.appspot.com](http://devappdemo.appspot.com)).

Now i want to create an android app for the same which should access the same datastore.
I googled it and i found that it can be done with CloudEndPoints but dont know from where to start how it can be done. Please suggest any tutorials or step by step instructions to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Endpoints would be the easiest way at the moment to get started with it. Here is the [overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/) and [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/).

Cloud Endpoints will help you generate the Endpoint API (REST API) and it also helps to generate the Android client code, that you can easily integrate into your Android application.

If you already have exposed your Python application over Web Services, you could directly use that from your Android application.

Comment: Romin Thank you. I gone through your blog its really nice explained.   I have created GAE app in python is it possible to create Endpoints API:in python and also is it possible to create client library for that to use in my android app. Because its like (python GAE app + Java Android app ) please help me. Thank you

Comment: Absolutely - you can do the same in Python too. Please refer to the docs : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/ and you can invoke the Python app services via Android. REST is agnostic when it comes to your platform of choice.