# Create an android app that uses the same datastore(GAE) as website

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I have a website in java with google app engine datastore as backend.I need to create an android app that uses same datastore as the website. I created the website in IntelliJ Idea IDE. I have used **'objectify'** to connect with datastore

Do I need to create the android app as a module under the website, if so, how to do that?

OR

Should I create the android app in android studio as an independent project? How will I connect the later with the website datastore?

I am an amateur so please explain your answer. Much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194847/how-to-access-app-engine-datastore-by-android-app I think that would be the preferred way: using cloud endpoints to connect to the java application and connecting to the datastore from there.

Comment: @dyeray I followed the link and able to add endPoints(backendApi) for java project in intelliJ and generate its android client library files. Please guide me how to use that library files in android studio and call the apis?

Comment: Take a look into this link: http://rominirani.com/2014/08/27/gradle-tutorial-part-10-consuming-endpoints-in-android-code/ the previous chapters (8, 9) explain cloud endpoints in more detail if you need it. It uses Android Studio, but it should be similar to IntelliJ.

Comment: thanks dyeray. I'll try this and let you know :)

Comment: hi dyeray.. I have generated endpoints in intellij of my '@entity' java class, when i try to access it using api explorer .. it shows me error message "    Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 400"

Comment: the error is coming because i am using Ref<> and key<> fields in class which endpoints dont support.. what to do??